# Azure SignalR Service running multiple hubs in different modes

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-functions, serverless, signalr-service

When SignalR Service came out, we were able to run the Hub in Classic mode, this allowed communication from both serverless functions (REST API) and asp.net core hubs (WS). Now according to the warning on the azure portal, the classic mode seems to be obsolete and shouldn't be used.

Warning message says: "Classic mode is obsoleted and error prune. Please use Default mode when all the hubs have hub servers, or use Serverless mode if not. If some of the hubs have hub servers while others not, we suggest creating two separate instances, one as Default and the other as Serverless."

In our scenario we have to use both ASP.NET Core hub for service client dashboards (JS + other functionality) and serverless functions that do background processing and send messages to SignalR Service to be seen on the dashboards. As the warning suggests this setup would require to run one hub in Default mode and one hub in Serverless mode, assuming the functions would talk to serverless and the ASP.NET core to Default mode hubs.

The main question then is, how would the communication between two SignalR Service hubs happen? We need the messages from serverless mode to appear on the Default mode hub clients. Is that even a valid scenario or should we move everything to one mode or the other instead?

I failed to find any documentation for this on the official Microsoft sites, any links explaining how the setup would look like and work is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For our particular use case where we use serverless functions to send messages to groups directly through SignalR Service, the answer is to use the "Default" mode, this mode will allow to use both servers and functions.